# Registered function for ng-change does not get fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement `ng-change` whenever input value is changed for the text-field.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js'></script>

        <div ng-app='transactionStatus'>

            <form ng-controller='formController'>
                <input type='text' ng-change='responder()' ng-model='message.query' />
                Reply: <span ng-bind='message.response'></span>
            </form>

        </div>  

        <script>


            function formController($scope) {
                    $scope.message = {query : 0};

                    $scope.responder = function(){
                        $scope.message.response = $scope.message.query * 100;
                        $scope.message = message; 
                    }
                }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

So, whenever the input value changes a function `responder` should be called and a text in return should be written for `ng-bind='message.response'` But it writes nothing when I type in the text-value. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: try with the `console.log` from your responder. Are you sure its not called? And `$scope.message=message` looks strange! What is a `message`? Seems you overwrite your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the controller to an angular module.
Change the script to

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('transactionStatus', []);
    app.controller('formController', function($scope) {
         $scope.message = {query : 0};

         $scope.responder = function(){
             $scope.message.response = $scope.message.query * 100;
             $scope.message = message; 
         }
    });
</script>
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_controller) example.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.message = message;` is messing the things here

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = {
    query: 0
  };

  $scope.responder = function() {
    $scope.message.response = $scope.message.query * 100;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <form>
    <input type='text' ng-change='responder()' ng-model='message.query' /> Reply: 
    <span ng-bind='message.response'></span>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNV8Jo2xbe6BOCLqhNSt?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't `message` get initialized as `$scope.message`? Why is `$scope.message = message` incorrect?

Comment: It gets defined as `$scope.message = {
    query: 0
  };`

Comment: Check your console, you will find `message is not defined` as `message` is defined under the context of `$scope.message`, `message` used without using `$scope` object will be undefined..